# Find Fenrig (Skyrim)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For ‘The Book Of Love’ quest, I’m on the objective ‘Find Fenrig’ but, all my quest marker is pointing to is a giants camp. Any ways I could fight the giants (without dying) or is the quest location somewhere else?

Comment: https://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Book_of_Love try reading through this. I can't remember much about the quest myself, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a traveling group of giants, I had mistaken Fenrig’s luminescence for a fire.